# Rust Async Executor Memory Ordering Guarantees When Moving Tasks Across Threads?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-async-std, rust-futures

This is a rather basic question regarding the memory ordering guarantees inside the Rust async ecosystems. However, I don't seem to find a clear answer anywhere.

[C++ memory ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Explanation) specifies the memory ordering from a thread-based perspective:

> ## Release-Acquire ordering
>
> If an atomic store in thread A is tagged memory_order_release and an atomic load in thread B from the same variable is tagged memory_order_acquire, all memory writes (non-atomic and relaxed atomic) that happened-before the atomic store from the point of view of thread A, become visible side-effects in thread B. That is, once the atomic load is completed, thread B is guaranteed to see everything thread A wrote to memory.

Various Rust async executors supports moving tasks across thread at `.await` points. A natural scenario would be:

1. Task A was at Thread 1 and performed a `Relaxed` store at variable `x`.
2. Task A hit a `.await` point
3. Task A was moved to Thread 2 and awaked. And then performed a `Release` store at variable `y`.
4. Task B was at Thread 3 and performed an `Acquire` load at variable `y`.

The question is: Is the `Relaxed` store from Thread 1 guaranteed to be visible in Task B after the `Acquire` load? E.g. if Task B at Thread 3 performed an `Relaxed` load at variable `x` afterwards, is it guaranteed that Task A's side effect will be visible?

This should depend on the implementation of synchronization mechanisms inside each async executor's task scheduler. Anyone familiar with them is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[Comment](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/discussions/4484#discussioncomment-2140741) from Tokio maintainer:

> When the task is moved from one thread to another, there is a synchronizes-with relation between the things before and after the .await. Depending on the exact circumstances, the synchronization comes from a mutex or an atomic using acquire & release semantics.

In C++ memory spec, *synchronizse-with* guarantees *inter-thread happens-before*. Therefore at least in Tokio, it should be safe to ignore memory ordering impact from a `.await` point.

Comment: All runtimes guarantee this because polling a future requires a mutable reference to it, and the happens-before relationship follows from the uniqueness guarantees of mutable references. It would be undefined behavior for a runtime to not make this guarantee.

Comment: Yes, I believe the same way. Uniqueness guarantee does lead to *happens-before*. However, I am mostly concerned about whether it is possible that any runtime unsafely optimize some Futures using relaxed atomics, since the nomicon does not seem to have defined this behavior.

Comment: Data races are the _first_ thing on the list of [behavior considered undefined](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html), and what you described would be a data race on the future. There is no runtime out there that does that (plus/minus bugs).